# How to import existing Docker server to Docker Machine?

Tags: docker-machine

I tried `docker-machine create -d none --url tcp://<ipaddr>:2376 remote` and copied `{ca,key,cert}.pem` (Client certs) to the machine directory. Then I did `eval "$(docker-machine env remote)"` which caused this error:

```
open /Users/uetchy/.docker/machine/machines/remote/server.pem: no such file or directory
```

I'm confusing why they need the **server.pem** even if client keys already exist.

How can I avoid to put a critical `server.pem` onto a local machine?

Comment: Any updates on this? have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the "generic" docker-machine driver: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Comment: generic driver seems to work with SSH for provisioning. Is there no option to import already provisioned servers?

Comment: The `generic` driver isn't the same as the `none` driver, as it attempts to actually install docker-engine, updates packages,messes with the hostname, and other things you don't want when you already have the server running. If `generic` had a `--dont-install` option, then it would be perfect for this use case.

Comment: Also came across that question - it has been discussed on Github, see https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3212

Comment: Please add a big WARNING that following the instructions to add a docker machine from the link you provided, will delete all docker containers on the host machine! There is no mention in the docker docs about this behavior. I just deleted all production containers on one of our servers...